# Copy a HTML table to a Word file - overwrite error

Tags: javascript, html, ms-word, html-table, export-to-word

I'm trying to copy a HTML table to a Word file.

In the first all the first column copied just fine to the word table.
When the code starts to copy the second column it is overwrite the first one.
I change the index of the column --> `Cell(i,0)/Cell(i,1)`.

Any idea why it happen?

```
  <script>
  function tab()
    {
    var NUMBER_OF_ROWS = 22;
    var NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS = 2;

    var objWord = new ActiveXObject("Word.Application");
    objWord.Visible = True
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add();

    var objRange = objDoc.Range();
    objDoc.Tables.Add (objRange, NUMBER_OF_ROWS, NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS);
    var objTable = objDoc.Tables(1);

    var thisTable = $(' .ms-table');

    for (var i=0;i<thisTable.rows.length;i++)
    {
        var oCell = thisTable.rows.item(i).cells;
        objTable.Cell(i,0).Range.Text = oCell.item(0).innerText;
    }

    for (var i=0;i<thisTable.rows.length;i++)
    {
        var oCell = thisTable.rows.item(i).cells;
        objTable.Cell(i,1).Range.Text = oCell.item(1).innerText;
    }

    objTable.AutoFormat(9)
    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please see if the below JavaScript code is helpful:

JavaScript :

```
        if (typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && typeof saveAs !== "undefined") {
    (function($) {
        $.fn.wordExport = function(fileName) {
            fileName = typeof fileName !== 'undefined' ? fileName : "jQuery-Word-Export";
            var static = {
                mhtml: {
                    top: "Mime-Version: 1.0\nContent-Base: " + location.href + "\nContent-Type: Multipart/related; boundary=\"NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY\";type=\"text/html\"\n\n--NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\nContent-Location: " + location.href + "\n\n<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html>\n_html_</html>",
                    head: "<head>\n<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\n<style>\n_styles_\n</style>\n</head>\n",
                    body: "<body>_body_</body>"
                }
            };
            var options = {
                maxWidth: 624
            };
            // Clone selected element before manipulating it
            var markup = $(this).clone();

            // Remove hidden elements from the output
            markup.each(function() {
                var self = $(this);
                if (self.is(':hidden'))
                    self.remove();
            });

            // Embed all images using Data URLs
            var images = Array();
            var img = markup.find('img');
            for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
                // Calculate dimensions of output image
                var w = Math.min(img[i].width, options.maxWidth);
                var h = img[i].height * (w / img[i].width);
                // Create canvas for converting image to data URL
                var canvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
                canvas.width = w;
                canvas.height = h;
                // Draw image to canvas
                var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                context.drawImage(img[i], 0, 0, w, h);
                // Get data URL encoding of image
                var uri = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                $(img[i]).attr("src", img[i].src);
                img[i].width = w;
                img[i].height = h;
                // Save encoded image to array
                images[i] = {
                    type: uri.substring(uri.indexOf(":") + 1, uri.indexOf(";")),
                    encoding: uri.substring(uri.indexOf(";") + 1, uri.indexOf(",")),
                    location: $(img[i]).attr("src"),
                    data: uri.substring(uri.indexOf(",") + 1)
                };
            }

            // Prepare bottom of mhtml file with image data
            var mhtmlBottom = "\n";
            for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
                mhtmlBottom += "--NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY\n";
                mhtmlBottom += "Content-Location: " + images[i].location + "\n";
                mhtmlBottom += "Content-Type: " + images[i].type + "\n";
                mhtmlBottom += "Content-Transfer-Encoding: " + images[i].encoding + "\n\n";
                mhtmlBottom += images[i].data + "\n\n";
            }
            mhtmlBottom += "--NEXT.ITEM-BOUNDARY--";

            //TODO: load css from included stylesheet
            var styles = "";

            // Aggregate parts of the file together
            var fileContent = static.mhtml.top.replace("_html_", static.mhtml.head.replace("_styles_", styles) + static.mhtml.body.replace("_body_", markup.html())) + mhtmlBottom;

            // Create a Blob with the file contents
            var blob = new Blob([fileContent], {
                type: "application/msword;charset=utf-8"
            });
            saveAs(blob, fileName + ".doc");
        };
    })(jQuery);
} else {
    if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
        console.error("jQuery Word Export: missing dependency (jQuery)");
    }
    if (typeof saveAs === "undefined") {
        console.error("jQuery Word Export: missing dependency (FileSaver.js)");
    }
}
$("a.jquery-word-export").click(function(event) {
            $("#page-content").wordExport();
        });
```

Html:

```
     <table class="ms-table">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>tab</button>

  <div class="col-xs-5">
                <a class="btn jquery-word-export" href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <span class="word-icon">W</span>
                    Export as .doc
                </a>
            </div>
```

Supporting Js files:

1. https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/2014-11-29/FileSaver.min.js

Comment: Hey, thannk. My problem is not to get the data, my problem is to put it in the word table. the first column  overwirting by the  second  column.